# SQL Server Date conversion questions

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with dates in this format. YYYYDDD

I need to convert them to YYYY-MM format

For example, I have a date `2016003` so this should become `2016-01`.

Similarly, date of `2016055` should become `2016-02`

Is there a way to display these without creating a user function?

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that what you have in your current table is NOT dates. They are numbers that represent dates. If at all possible you should stop storing date information as numbers or strings. They should be stored as dates or datetime. It will make your life SO much less painful.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is to add the days to the beginning of the year.  So, to get the date:

```
select dateadd(day, cast(right(col, 3) as int) - 1,
               cast(left(col, 4) + '01-01' as date)
              ) as dte
```

You can then format it as you want.  For instance, in SQL Server 2012+, you can use `format()`:

```
select format(dateadd(day, cast(right(col, 3) as int) - 1,
                      cast(left(col, 4) + '01-01' as date)
                     ), 'YYYYMM'
              ) as yyyymm
```